# Changing code examples to correct the mistake asked in the question

Tags: discussion, edits

I hate reading questions with code and thinking "huh, what's wrong" only to realise the questioner changed the code after receiving the answer. What can be done to actually encourage users not to change code samples after asking the question?

The Code Review site, for example, clearly states not to change code after it's posted.

One assumes they have their reasons, real names are used by some users, so hiding the mistake may seem a good idea for future job applications, or maybe they just want to "help" future seekers by putting the correct code at the top. Whatever the reason, I think it's wrong and it should be discouraged.

Comment: You can rollback the edit and leave a comment. If OP keeps editing the question, you can notify a moderator by flagging the question.

Comment: @GergoErdosi That is correct, but the OP in this case does not have full editing privileges, so cannot rollback posts unless they are his/her own.

Comment: It's not always the OP performing the edit, I've seen other users 'correct' original code too. Roll it back as per @CodyGray's answer.

Comment: @AstroCB Users with no "rollback" button can still edit starting from the last good revision and just hit submit without changing anything (except the comment, of course), which will effectively roll back the post.

Comment: @Michelle True: Gergo just made it sound like it was as easy as pressing a button for everyone, which it is not if you don't have full editing privileges.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should I make edits to code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**It *is* discouraged**, for precisely the reason you cite: it invalidates the question.

If you see somewhere where this has happened, you should roll back the edit.

Honestly, worrying about "mistakes" in your questions is a little bit silly. If someone really wants to know, they can always look at the revision history to see what big blunder you made. But it is implicit in the fact that you asked a question that you didn't know something. No reasonable employer would hold this against you. Rather, they would judge you positively on the basis that you recognized the limitations of your knowledge and knew where to find the answer. As far as future viewers are concerned, the correct version already occupies a prominent position: the topmost accepted answer!

Comment: "No reasonable employer" I've never heard of a "reasonable employer" :P

Comment: @bjb568 if your employer have read your comment and didn't fire you, it means that he/she at least has a reasonable sense of humor :P